# Regex expression in grep not respecting conditional clause?

Tags: regex, grep

The following regex expression

```
 (created|modified|renamed) mode
```

When given these inputs

```
created mode 123
created sfs
 abc
 aasdf foobar
 foo1\nfoo2
```

returns:

`created mode` as a global match with the following capture gruops.

[image]

How do I get the same results when using `grep`?  Here is what happens:

```
echo -e 'created mode 123\n created sfs\n abc\n aasdf foobar\n foo1\nfoo2' | grep '(created\|new file\|modified) mode'
echo -e 'created mode 123\n created sfs\n abc\n aasdf foobar\n foo1\nfoo2' | grep '(created\|new file\|modified mode)'
echo -e 'created mode 123\n created sfs\n abc\n aasdf foobar\n foo1\nfoo2' | grep 'created\|new file\|modified mode'
created mode 123
 created sfs
```

Where only the last `grep` (without the () around the "or" condition) returns results.

I have tried this both on `macOS` and `ubuntu`.

**Update** Trying with `grep -E`

`echo -e 'created mode 123\n created sfs\n abc\n aasdf foobar\n foo1\nfoo2' | grep -E '(created\|new file\|modified) mode'`

Gives no results

**Another update** I missed a piece of the comment from @Barmar:  need to unescape the pipe when using `-E`.

`echo -e 'created mode 123\n created sfs\n abc\n aasdf foobar\n foo1\nfoo2' | grep -E '(created\|new file\|modified) mode'`

[Correctly] gives

```
 created mode 123
```

Comment: Please add sample input (no descriptions, no images, no links) and your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: The sample inputs is shown *in text*.  The output should be clear as well but i'll add the text in any case

Comment: Either use `grep -E` and don't escape `|`, or escape the `(` and `)`.

Comment: @Barmar  `grep -E` returned *no* results at least on macos. I'll add that example as well to the question

Comment: You should also say that you're on MacOS -- it has BSD grep rather than GNU grep.

Comment: @Barmar  I did mention already in the question

Comment: Did you read what I said? If you use `-E`, you do NOT escape the pipes.

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/html_node/Basic-vs-Extended.html

Comment: @Barmar I missed that about the escaping. Trying now.  Yes that works. Feel encouraged to make an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use basic regular expression, you have to escape `(` as well as `|`.

```
echo -e 'created mode 123\n created sfs\n abc\n aasdf foobar\n foo1\nfoo2' | grep '\(created\|new\|modified\) mode'
```

Or you can use extended regexp with `-E`, then you must not escape either of them.

```
echo -e 'created mode 123\n created sfs\n abc\n aasdf foobar\n foo1\nfoo2' | grep -E '(created|new|modified) mode'
```